# Using "contains" to find a string within an entry

Tags: conditional, contains

I am trying to use a conditional on an entry detail page to show a section only if a certain field contains a "t" in it. This is what I have but it doesn't appear to be working no matter what I have tried. In this case the "t" will always be a part of a greater string (product ID).

```
{% if entry.intro|contains('*t*') %}
  <p>TEST</p>
{% endif %}
```

I feel like this is so straightforward, but I'm just missing it! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contains` filter works on an array of items and accepts 2 arguments, namely a key and a value to search on, as per the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#contains). So the `contains` filter would be useful, for example, to check whether one or more entries in an array of entries contains a `t` in their intro.

If I’m understanding your question correctly, you want to check whether a string contains a value, in which case you can use the `in` [containment operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#containment-operator).

```
{% if 't' in entry.intro %}
    {# ... #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!